# JQueryUI DatePicker inside html iFrame doesn't expand past the frame

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-ui

I have an ASP.net aspx page that's composed of 3 iframes. One for the header, one for the side menu and one for the main content area. The header frame has 2 date fields that will apply some kind of filter on the data in the main area.

I have to change the date fields to something more user friendly, so I figured I would use some jquery datepickers.

The problem I have is that the height of iframe is smaller than the height of the datepicker selection window. Instead of appearing on top of the other frames, the date picker is not displayed entirely (stops at the end of the iframe).

I tried a lot of z-index fiddling, but it seems to me like all this only applies to the page inside the iframe, and does not affect how it's displayed on the main page.

Any suggestions? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible. An iframe is a self-contained document, like a page in a different browser window. As long as you're using iframes any content in them will end at the iframe's border.

You will also find that it's a load of trouble getting the scripts in the different iframes to communicate with each other, especially in older browsers and intranet viewers (also called Internet Explorer).

In short: If there is no reason to use an iframe, don't use one. Having three of them on a page is like having four web pages open in the browser at the same time and is generally a waste of resources. Using an iframe makes sense when you need to load content eg. from a different domain and you want it isolated from the content on your page.

Comment: Ok, that's kind of what I thought. This website was designed a long time ago by other developers, I'm the guy who's supposed to fix this mess. I guess I'll have to find a way to fit those 3 frames in the same page. 

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but it might help someone :

You can increase and decrease the row of frameset dynamically :

```
$("#fromdate, #todate").click(function () {
        $('frameset', top.document).eq(2).attr('rows', '300,*');
    });
```